# Individually handling Unique Constraint violations with an Entity containing two or more Constraints

Tags: haskell, error-handling, uniqueidentifier, yesod, persistent

I have a User entity with two unique constraints:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
User
    ident Text
    email Text
    ...
    UniqueUser ident
    UniqueUserEmail email
|]
```

This entity has two possible fields for which it can throw a Unique constraint violation, and I'd like to be able to handle each one individually. Unfortunately, the [`insertUnique`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.8/persistent-2.2.4.1/Database-Persist-Class.html#insertUnique) function can only tell me that ***some*** constraint was violated, but not ***which***.

Though `replaceUnique` returns the `Unique` violation, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent functionality for `insert`-based functions.

So, it seems like `checkUnique` is my best option, and I've tried to roll out something that uses some of the lower-level functions in the [`PersistEntity`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.8/persistent-2.2.4.1/Database-Persist-Class.html#t:PersistEntity) class (specifically the `persistUniqueToFieldNames` and `persistUniqueKeys` functions), but the best thing I can think to come up with would use fairly shoddy string-equality to handle the appropriate violation, as opposed to data-type matching.

Before I dived in deeper to a stringly-typed implementation, I thought I'd ask here if there was a better way to solve this type of problem. Thank you all for your time.